# Possible missing firmware

Tags: linux, router, debian, dd-wrt

**I found a script that analyzes what missing firmware you have and installs them for you**

credits to this guy for creating the script : https://gist.github.com/zas/205372c824decb8e121baec2f86e1415

I was updating `wifite` on Kali Linux when a warning appeared. It said that a possible firmware is missing. I am running Kali Linux in dual-boot with the latest version that has every possible tool. The command that I used for updating `wifite` was `apt upgrade wifite`

I have tried installing many linux firmware like `firmware-misc-nonfree` , and `firmware-linux` and `firmware-linux-nonfree` but the warnings keep appearing they all say that they are in the newest version and installed

```
# apt upgrade wifite                                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wifite is already the newest version (2.6.0+ds1-1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3-cachecontrol python3-cssselect python3-flask-cors python3-gevent python3-pem python3-pyquery python3-pywebcopy
  python3-zope.event
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  blueman intel-microcode kali-menu libhtml-form-perl powershell-empire
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 64.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 27.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 blueman amd64 2.3.2-1 [1,086 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 intel-microcode amd64 3.20220809.1 [4,099 kB]
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 kali-menu all 2022.4.0 [7,416 kB]
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libhtml-form-perl all 6.10-1 [24.0 kB]
Get:5 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 powershell-empire all 4.7.3-kali-0kali1 [51.6 MB]
Fetched 64.2 MB in 21s (3,036 kB/s)                                                                                                    
(Reading database ... 712751 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../blueman_2.3.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking blueman (2.3.2-1) over (2.3.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../intel-microcode_3.20220809.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking intel-microcode (3.20220809.1) over (3.20220510.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../kali-menu_2022.4.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking kali-menu (2022.4.0) over (2022.3.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-form-perl_6.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-form-perl (6.10-1) over (6.09-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../powershell-empire_4.7.3-kali-0kali1_all.deb ...
Unpacking powershell-empire (4.7.3-kali-0kali1) over (4.7.1-kali-0kali1) ...
Setting up kali-menu (2022.4.0) ...
Setting up powershell-empire (4.7.3-kali-0kali1) ...
Setting up intel-microcode (3.20220809.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
intel-microcode: microcode will be updated at next boot
Setting up blueman (2.3.2-1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/xdg/autostart/blueman.desktop ...
blueman-mechanism.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up libhtml-form-perl (6.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.18.0-kali5-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_14.bin for module i915
```

also when running `update-initramfs -u` the same warnings appears

```
# update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.18.0-kali5-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_14.bin for module i915
```

Comment: `i915` refers to the Intel Graphics driver. It's normal it not installing firmware that isn't required for specific chips not present, "W" means warning, not an error. And using Kali implies a solid Linux foundation - 3rd time in less than an hour I had to repeat this truism -, a foundation you don't have if you need to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Next time please use proper capitalization, sentences, punctuation, paragraphs, grammar, etc., and properly format code - use {_} - as code. Thanks.

Comment: The question is difficult to understand because of the formatting. Please pay attention to formatting, grammar, etc.... This will make the question easier to answer

Comment: ok thank you for letting me know about the formatting I enchaced the formatting